# Building OpenCV.js fails. CMake can't find installed compilers?

Tags: javascript, opencv, web, computer-vision

I have the following directory structure:

```
~/emsdk
~/opencv
```

I am trying to build OpenCV.js

I do

```
cd ~/opencv
python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js --emscripten_dir=~/emsdk/
```

Which results in:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:100 (message):
  Could not find toolchain file:
  ~/emsdk/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:135 (project)


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 227, in <module>
    builder.config()
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 167, in config
    execute(cmd)
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 23, in execute
    raise Fail("Child returned: %s" % retcode)
__main__.Fail: Child returned: 1
```

Both gcc and g++ are installed in the system.
Prior of running this I went to ~/emsdk and ran:

```
./emsdk update
./emsdk install latest
./emsdk activate latest
source ./emsdk_env.sh
```

I am not sure why this is failing. I am trying to follow this [tutorial][1].

EDIT:

I am doing this on Ubuntu, if it helps

EDIT 2:

It seems an important part of the problem comes from the message:

```
 CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:100 (message):
      Could not find toolchain file:
      ~/emsdk/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake
```

There is no `emsdk/cmake` directory.

EDIT 3:

Posting answer, it was the path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is a stupid assumption on my end. Writing:

```
python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js --emscripten_dir=~/emsdk/
```

Is the wrong command, the correct one is:

```
python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js --emscripten_dir=/home/username/emsdk/emscripten/1.38.30/
```

Comment: It helped me with the same issue, thanks for sharing.

Comment: for me I was able to do it like this: `python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js --emscripten_dir ~/Documents/dev/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/;`

Answer (score 4):

For me, this works:
python ./platforms/js/build_js.py build_js --emscripten_dir=/home/username/emsdk/upstream/emscripten

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.

Comment: This helped me too, the accepted answer didn't work for me , but this did, thanks

Comment: For me on macos, this is working and not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

On MACOSX:

It works:

python /path-to/opencv-src/platforms/js/build_js.py  /path-to/build_js --emscripten_dir=/path-to/emsdk/upstream/emscripten

Note:

- Important: --emscripten_dir=/path-to/emsdk/upstream/emscripten
- build_js: let create a empty folder

Thanks All.